# How to change from bootstrap to bootstrap-sass and avoid dependency conflicts

Tags: gruntjs, dependencies, yeoman, bower, bootstrap-sass

I just started working on this Angular app that was setup using Yeoman. The packages used in the app are (along with others) are:

```js
"bootstrap": "~3.3.2",
"angular-bootstrap-nav-tree": "*",
"angular-strap": "~2.1.6"
```

Instead of the *bootstrap* package (which uses Less), I want to use *bootstrap-sass*. The problem is that *angular-bootstrap-nav-tree* and *angular-strap* have  *bootstrap* as dependency (not bootstrap-sass). This results in Bootstrap being loaded twice into index.html (by *usemin* package) when I run `grunt build`.

I guess there are more than one solution to this problem but I have not fount one.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Find other packages to replace *angular-bootstrap-nav-tree* and *angular-strap*.
2. Find a way to make *usemin* not add the extra bootstrap files to index.html.
3. Stop this nonsense and just use less.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the posible solution could be the second one using `exclude` for the specific file and avoid it to be copied twice.

For example, if you don't want two `bootstrap.js`, exclude one of them:

```
exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js']
```

Look at this [comment](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/538#issuecomment-64957016)